# Get list ASINs from amazon for a brand

Tags: amazon-web-services

I need to get list of product ASIN number in amazon.

http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=sr_nr_p_89_0?fst=as%3Aoff&rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3ASATCO%2Cp_89%3ASatco&keywords=SATCO&ie=UTF8&qid=1429810986&rnid=2528832011

above link in brand is "STACO" now how to get all product ASIN number.

We have used AWS API amazon.

Comment: we have used aws api like below which change to get brand product ASIN number

 $response = $amazonEcs->category('DVD')->responseGroup('Large')->search("Matrix Revolutions");

$response = $amazonEcs->responseGroup('Large')->optionalParameters(array('Brand' => 'SATCO'))->lookup('B0038VGT8U');